# End JavaScript function and all its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, canvas

I have a function in JavaScript  that will run and wont stop once activated, i need a way of completely stopping this funcrtion and all of its content and events

```
line.addEventListener('click', function () {
   $(function(){

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
   var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
  var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
window.alert(offsetX);
    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;
   var canvas2 = $("#canvas");



    function drawLine(toX,toY,context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(startX, startY);
        context.lineTo(toX,toY);
        context.stroke();
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // save drag-startXY, 
      // move temp canvas over main canvas,
      // set dragging flag
      startX=mouseX;
      startY=mouseY;
      contextTemp.clearRect(0,0,canvasTemp.width,canvasTemp.height);
      $("#canvasTemp").css({ left:0, top:0 });
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(!isDown){return;}
      // clear dragging flag
      // move temp canvas offscreen
      // draw the user's line on the main canvas
      isDown=false;
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      drawLine(mouseX,mouseY,context);
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      e.preventDefault();        
      if(!isDown){return;}
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      // clear the temp canvas
      // on temp canvas draw a line from drag-start to mouseXY
      contextTemp.clearRect(0,0,canvasTemp.width,canvasTemp.height);
      drawLine(mouseX,mouseY,contextTemp);
    }

  canvas2.mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    canvas2.mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  canvas2.mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
 canvas2.mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});


}); // end $(function(){});
});
```

This function needs to stop running on a variable click e.g a stop button

but it cannot stop all the other functions running

Comment: Which function needs to stop running?

Comment: could you explain more what is your problem, I just see that there is a function that executes on a click ...

Comment: You cannot stop a function from running, you can however use a flag to determine whether something needs to be executed or not. Also maybe [the jQuery one function](http://api.jquery.com/one/) can be of help.

Comment: This ocde is for drawing a line, it is on a canvas application so when a user cli cks the line button it will allow them to draw a line however i want it to stop drawing that line when they click a stop button, so i would like to know how to finnish this function

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you unbind the events you set in the first place, since you already using jQuery you can do sg. like:

```
var handleMouseDown = function(e) {
  /* ... */
};

// bind the event:
$( "#canvas" ).bind( "click", handler );

// unbind again:
$( "#canvas" ).unbind( "click", handler );
```

To delete a function:

```
 var fn = function() {
     alert( 1 );
 }
 fn();
 fn = undefined;
 fn();
```

Comment: i would if i knew how to unbind the events but i dont because the events look like this, if they were in a different format i could but i dont know how code below

Comment: canvas2.mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    canvas2.mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  canvas2.mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
 canvas2.mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});

Comment: havent tried it yet will do it tomorrow :D will let you know im hoping for good results lol

Comment: I cant get this bit of code that you showed to work i dont know if im doing it right though its a little confusing. Can you help me sructure it the way you think i should do it?